# Better way to dispose EF context in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple MagazineRepository class

```
public class MagazineRepository : IDisposable
{
    //EntityFramewokr context
    private DataBaseContext _context;

    public MagazineRepository() 
    {            
        _context = new DataBaseContext();
    }    

    public void Dispose()
    {
    if (_context != null) 
    { 
        _context.Dispose(); 
    } 
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And a simple controller:

```
public class MagazineController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult Index()
    {     
        //Should to implement using to dispose
        using(MagazineRepository magazineRepository = new MagazineRepository())
        {
            var magazine = magazineRepository.GetAll().ToList(); //Should use ToList() to avoid "Object has been disposed exception".
            return View(magazine);
        }
    }       
}
```

What if i don't want to use "using" and "ToList()" in each Action? What if i will call Dispose() context method in the destructor of the controller? Something like this:

```
public class MagazineController : Controller
{      
    MagazineRepository _magazineRepository;
    public MagazineController()
    {
        _magazineRepository= new MagazineRepository();
    }
    ~MagazineRepository();   
    {
        if(_magazineRepository!=null)
        {
            _magazineRepository.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {              
        var magazine = magazineRepository.GetAll();  
         return View(magazine);              
    }       
}
```

This code works, but i think it should be written in some other way. Context is able to live too long in last code example.
So are there any patterns that can give me my db records without "using" and "ToList()" each time?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this line: So are there any patterns that can give me my db records without "using" and "ToList()" each time? As far as I have understand your question, using(){ ... } will serve your way. Why you are explicitly disposing object. You are writing managed code so GarbegCollector will handle this task for you.

Comment: In eventual application i will use 10 actions and several calls of repository methods in each. So i will have to write "using" for each one. So i wondered if i can avoid it. Is it ok to dispose() an Entity Framework context in the destructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone answered my question, but then deleted it. Idea is to override Dispose method of the controller, because controller is disposing after action execution.

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{        
    protected IMyRepository _repository;       

    public RhotCMSController()
    {
        _repository = new MyRepository();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_repository != null)
            {
                _repository.Dispose();
            }               
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

 public class MyController : MyBaseController
 {  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {              
        var entities = _repository.GetAll();  
        return View(entities);              
    } 
 }
```

Comment: why dispose working but ~MagazineRepository() not working

Comment: ~MagazineRepository() will also be called, but the GC decides when (see finalizers in C# docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers).
The `using` statement calls `Dispose()` exactly when the block is exited.